# Cannot find the view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">

<head>
  <script src="/js/angular-1.5.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/angular-1.5.2/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- <p>Hello</p> -->
  <div ng-view></div>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
'use strict';

var PORT = 8080;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var qs = require('querystring');
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/views/index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT);

console.log('Server listenning on port ' + PORT);
```

```js
phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngRoute','phonecatControllers']);
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: '/views/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

These are my related files. I am building a simple application with AngularJS and NodeJS but the problem is that when i try to access root page through NodeJS (localhost:8080), there is a error in the console which says "angular.js:11500 GET http://localhost:8080/views/phone-list.html 404 (Not Found)". Can anybody suggest what i am doing wrong with this that my page is not being loaded through ng-view directive.

Comment: What does your file directory look like? Have you tried opening that html file in the browser to check that the file path matches?

Comment: File directory structure is app/views/index.html and similarly i have app/views/phone-list.html. When i try to open that it works fine but does not seem to fetch it when tried through server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the absolute url in the templateUrl.

```
phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', ['ngRoute','phonecatControllers']);
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'views/phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      }).
      when('/phones/:phoneId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/phone-detail.html',
        controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/phones'
      });
  }]);
```

Look at this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating).

Comment: If i do something like this when('/phones', {
        templateUrl: 'phone-list.html',
        controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'
      })  // It still does not work

Comment: I have already seen the tutorial but this does not seem to work for me. I am using the same concepts as explained in the tutorial.